# Warhammer Munchkin Boggleeye uses all your one shots on itself?

Tags: munchkin

The Boggleeye says that it uses all your one shots with a combat bonus to help itself. Does that include one shots that would normally only give a combat bonus to a munchkin? It would seem to me that it does, but there has been some contention at the table over it.